# django-tagging install fails

Tags: python

i am getting this error while installing django-tagging,

```
krisdigitx-Satellite-Pro-L450D django-tagging # python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 49, in <module>
    version_tuple = __import__('tagging').VERSION
  File "/home/site/krisdigitx/django-tagging/tagging/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tagging.managers import ModelTaggedItemManager, TagDescriptor
  File "/home/site/krisdigitx/django-tagging/tagging/managers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'krisdigitx.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named krisdigitx.settings
krisdigitx-Satellite-Pro-L450D django-tagging #
```

I have exported the environment variable on the commandline

declare -x DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="krisdigitx.settings"

but i still get the error that the module cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/krisdigitx

Comment: try export path to one level before krisdigitx, so..export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/

Comment: i have installed django-tagging, and while starting the server it gives no module found "tagging", where is this located,should i add this to pythonpath?

Comment: you should add tagging module to setup.py if you didn't already.